# span innertext doesn't assigning in same page even

Tags: asp.net, session, listview, html

actually i have to access the tax & total from the cart table as given below , and then assign them to the span in aspx page by assigning those values to their innertext,

i'd used breakpoint & debuged my code BUT the problen is too complicated...--> i'd seen that the innertext(assigned text) correctly showing by pointing mouse there at debugging in bindtotal() method,,, but this text not showing on the .aspx page,,,i mean that span text on aspx page still being empty even assigned.        why ??????

**.aspx**

```
<b>subtotal:</b>
<span id="span_subtotal" runat="server"></span>                         
<br/>
<b>Total:</b>                           
<span id="span_granttotal" runat="server"></span>
```

**.cs**

the innertext of these spans r sitll empty to run the below code............can any one help me about this ????????

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {            
        if (Session["cart_table"] == null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new Spcart().GetCart();
            Session["cart_table"] = dt;                  
        }
        BindCartListView();            
    }
}

public void bindtotal(int tax, int total)
{
    int ptax = 0;
    ptax = ptax + tax;

    int subtotal = 0;
    subtotal = subtotal + total;

    int granttotal = 0;
    granttotal = granttotal + ptax +subtotal;

    ///////////setting innertext///////////////////////

    span_subtotal.InnerText = subtotal.ToString();
    span_granttotal.InnerText = granttotal.ToString();
}

public void BindCartListView()
{                        
    DataTable producttable = new BALCate().GetProductDeatils(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["pid"].ToString()));
    DataTable carttable = (DataTable)Session["cart_table"];
    DataRow cartrow;
    DataRow productrow;

        cartrow = carttable.NewRow();
        productrow = producttable.Rows[0];
        cartrow["Pid"] = productrow["pid"];
        cartrow["PImage"] = productrow["pimg_mid1"];
        cartrow["Pprice"] = productrow["pcost"];
        cartrow["Pqty"] = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["qty"].ToString());                
        cartrow["Pname"] = productrow["pname"];
        cartrow["ptax"] = productrow["ptax"];
        cartrow["Total"] = int.Parse(productrow["pcost"].ToString()) * int.Parse(cartrow["Pqty"].ToString());  

        carttable.Rows.Add(cartrow);        

        int tax=int.Parse(cartrow["Ptax"].ToString());
        int total = int.Parse(cartrow["Total"].ToString());
        bindtotal(tax, total);        

 ListView_Cart.DataSource = carttable;
 ListView_Cart.DataBind();
 Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be the fact that you are doing a `Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");` at the end of the `BindCartListView()` method.

I don't know in what page the code behind you posted is from, but you could save the values in `Session`, or send them as a query string, and set it in the *ShoppingCart.aspx* code behind.

QueryString pseudo code:

```
Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx?subtotal=" + subtotal + "&granttotal=" + granttotal);
```

*ShoppingCart.aspx.cs* code behind pseudo code:

```
// Provided you have these span elements in ShoppingCart.aspx.
span_subtotal.InnerText = Request.QueryString["subtotal"];
span_granttotal.InnerText = Request.QueryString["granttotal"];
```

Comment: then what will b solution , without removing it (Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx")), bcoz of its necessity ??????????????

Comment: @AshokKumaram I updated the answer. I do not know what pages you have more, so it's just some pseudo code to get you started.

Comment: :i'hv explain it more in next question ,plz see my next question
i'd fixed it as u said that page redirects & loaded again, so that span becomes empty , i'd fixed it by some more affords , but still doesnt working....
plz see it soon n solve my problem...